# Unmatch when Slash( / ) is followed by Underscore( _ ) or hyphen( - )

Tags: regex

I am constructing an ID, in Javascript, which doesn't allow special character and uppercase letter. We could have `/ _ -` in the ID, but the it should not begin with these.

- hello *correct*
- helloWorld *incorrect*
- 123hello *correct*
- hello/world *correct*
- -hello *incorrect*
- _hello *incorrect*
- $hello *incorrect*
- /hello *incorrect*
- hello$ *incorrect*
- hello_world *correct*
- hello-world *correct*
- hello-world/apple *correct*
- hello_world/apple *correct*
- hello_world/apple123 *correct*

I have the following regEx which almost handles all the cases, however there is one case where if slash(/) is present it should not be followed by hyphen(-) or underscore(_), which i am unable to solve

> ^(?=.{1,50}$)(([a-z0-9])+([-_/a-z0-9])*)$

- hello_world/-apple *incorrect*
- hello_world/_apple *incorrect*
- hello_world//apple *incorrect*

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need a negative lookahead. Also, please don't spam a load of unrelated tags. There is a `[language-agnostic]` tag if a question doesn't apply to any specific programming language, though I expect the `[regex]` tag by itself is sufficient for your question.

Comment: Please only tag the programming language that applies.

Comment: Do you want `^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_\/][a-z0-9]+)*$`?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew this solved the issue, but now things like hello_ hello- hello/ unmatch.

Comment: Then, `^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_\/][a-z0-9]+)*[-_\/]?$`?

Comment: This one works perfectly for all the scenarios!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:[-_\/][a-z0-9]+)*[-_\/]?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PsAbh1/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `(?=.{1,50}$)` - there can only be 1 to 50 chars in the string
- `[a-z0-9]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters or digits
- `(?:[-_\/][a-z0-9]+)*`  - zero or more sequences of

  - `[-_\/]` - a `-`, `_` or `/` char
  - `[a-z0-9]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters or digits
- `[-_\/]?` - an optional `-`, `_` or `/` char
- `$` - end of string.